How to make thick outline? My shader doesn't work
current situation
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rx8frh
I’m trying to make a thick outline for the specific mesh.
I tried some existing solutions (Outline in @react-three/postprocess and Outlines in @react-three/drei and so on), but these solutions couldn’t fully be satisfied with me. Then I made a custom shader which made with outlines from normal vectors and a depth buffer.
The outline is applied only to the specific object, but it can also be seen through other objects.
I want to make outlines hidden when the specific object is hidden by the other object.
Can anyone help me? Thanks.
Goal Situation

Please put a minimal code example in your question, helping readers to understand the problem.
